# Free way to share large files (50MB) over the Internet?

Tags: internet, file-transfer

I need to send a approximately 50 MB [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) file.  My email provider will not allow me to send attachments that big.

Is there a free service out there that I can upload my file to and allow someone else a password to download it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SkyDrive](http://skydrive.live.com/) (Windows Live) allows up to 50 MB files, within a total of 25 GB of free storage.

Comment: Wow, freaking 50MiB? And all for a simple account on WindowsLive?

Answer (score 15):

[Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com)!
While Dropbox's primary focus is on syncing files between computers, it comes with a fancy Public folder, which basically means anything placed in there is uploaded and given a download URL accessible to the outside world. You can grab a download link from either right-clicking on the file or using the web UI. I cannot find anything regarding a file size limit on the site itself, and although it does mention you'll probably be e-mailed for questioning if you use considerable bandwidth, I've (Phoshi) never had an issue sharing files upwards of 600mb through it.

Comment: Why Dropbox? Explain some of why you think it's a good answer instead of just posting a link.

Comment: @Grammar Nazi; this is a community driven site, don't feel like you have to hold back on the editing!

Comment: Agreed - Dropbox is a really amazing service. Seamless to use, simple to set up.

Comment: I guess I can expand his answer. Will do that next time.

Comment: @Grammar Nazi: too many edits will force a post to be CommunityWiki (meaning the answerer no longer gets rep from upvotes).  try to make all your changes in as few edits as possible.

Comment: I edited in order to upvote, I then asked it on Meta.

Answer (score 3):

[File Apartment](http://www.fileapartment.com)

Easy to use, no software to download, no registration required, up to 1 GB, free option, safe, and secure.

*Disclaimer: I'm related to them.*

Comment: That looks sweet!  I already sent my file or I would use that.  While the one day limit makes the free version a bit less useful, the fact that the others are on a file by file basis and don't cost a lot makes that ok.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.yousendit.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Create a torrent file](http://torrentfreak.com/how-to-create-a-torrent/) and share it via email or your messenger program.

If the receiver is accustomed to downloading via torrent, it can be a very fast solution for sharing files of any size with one or more person.

Answer (score 2):

[Adrive.com](http://www.adrive.com/) gives you 50gb.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several services:

www.mydrive.ch will give you 1GB free memory online, with guest access, if you wish to.

www.gmx.net will give you the media center with 1GB (i think) for the free account where you can change files like you want.

Filehoster like Rapidshare.com, Netload.in and others give you the simple solution to this, but there your data is not safe, even if you protected the upload with a password, you should encrypt your data there.

If possible I would recommend you a direct send like using instant messaging ICQ, XMPP or other services, that way you really know where your data is going.

Answer (score 0):

`Bittorrent Sync` is my tool of choice:

Pro's:

- does not require registration
- transfer goes from originating machine to recipient, directly, third-party server is used only in link negotiation
- transfers are encrypted
- transfers are chunked/resumable

Con's:

- both machines have to be online simultaneously for the transfer to start
- i, personally, don't like some of new versions features, am using v1.3.109, last of 1.3 branch.