# Method for transfering large files for newbies

Tags: file-transfer

One of my friends is now in China and wants to send me his home-made video files. I have a Linux hosting account on GoDaddy and I've configured an FTP account for him. Unfortunately he's having trouble in using the FTP account.

Can you recommend a better option?

Comment: see: http://superuser.com/questions/30204/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-do-a-direct-file-transfer-of-an-extremely-large-file-o and http://superuser.com/questions/121995/free-way-to-share-large-files-over-the-internet

Comment: A description of the problem he is having would help.

Comment: Also http://superuser.com/questions/42747/best-way-to-transfer-27-gb-from-a-pc-to-another-online/

Comment: None of these related questions focus on the "newbie" approach, they are rather on a quite technical and optimal point of view, in my opinion. This question should remain open, and solutions should emphasize on the "easy way to do it".

Comment: I agree with Gnoupi: I would love to know of a solution my grandmother could use

Comment: @Ivo: You want a PtP mass file transfer application that's simple enough for Grandma to use, and complex enough to be efficient while being error resilient. It's highly unlikely you'll find that combination anywhere.

Comment: @Chris - Actually, the question is more simple than what you state. The question is really about simple ways to transfer a large file. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Darn, as a mod I couldn't just vote for it to be opened. Well if the community or another mod disagrees, feel free to close it.

Comment: @Ivo: it looks all-good from here.  agree it should stay open.

Comment: I don't agree, but then I can't vote to close again :-s I think a "newbie-focused" answer can also be added to the dupe. No need to keep this open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's 2 GB or less (at a time), [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) is a good option, it's utterly dead simple to use, and you can either share account to account, or put it in the web accessable public account. Also if one of you recommends the other, you get an extra 250 MB space.

Answer (score 1):

Note that most of browsers are showing FTPs on a quite transparent way.

If you give a direct link to your file, like a ftp://user:password@yoursite.home (note sure fully about the syntax, though), he won't even have to bother with using a FTP client. It will be like downloading a regular file from Internet. It could be a way to make it easier, using what you already prepared.

Comment: Note that the user who asked the question is the receiver, not the sender.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be for both of you to create an Ubuntuone (or similar service) account, have him save those files to his Ubuntuone account and then share them to your account.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is smaller than 200 MB, use [www.mailbigfile.com](http://www.mailbigfile.com) to send the file. You may even find it's worth paying for their pro account as it's pretty cheap and possibly more convenient than the (good) alternatives already suggested.

Comment: Why did my comment need editing peter? Did I make a mistake?

Answer (score -1):

Snailmail and Sneakernet are still some fast and cheap bulk data transport services.

Comment: -1 Certainly not for getting data from China to the US...

Comment: Just because you can come up with a single example doesn't make it untrue for many situations.