# How can I transfer a 4GB VM over the net?

Tags: file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free way to share large files over the Internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/121995/free-way-to-share-large-files-over-the-internet)

I have a 4GB VMWare VM (created using VM Player). I need to get it to someone at the other end of the country. Is there a free service I can use to send it over the net? Does DropBox allow files of 4GB to be transferred?

Comment: A USB drive through the post?

Comment: If possible I would like to xfer it over the net.

Comment: Note: compress it using 7Zip.

Comment: Yes, I've compressed it and got it down to just under 2G so I'll try DropBox.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up an FTP server on one machine and connect the other to it. An example of a server would be [SmallFTPd](http://smallftpd.sourceforge.net/).

In order for this to work the server machine needs allow incoming requests.

Alternatively, you could use an archiving tool to split your file into 2*2GB and use DropBox (as, if I remember correctly, the free file size limit is 2GB).

Answer (score 1):

I personally would go for something more direct then the upload then download to some website as most will not allow 4GB of transfer.  GChat has a file transfer option I believe and I've used Hamachi in the past to securely transfer large files around.